# How to use Static Analysis of any chess engine

Tags: engines, stockfish

Probably all chess engine uses static analysis to evaluate the position and find moves.
My question is that how can a human make use of static analysis?
In Stockfish static analysis comes using the command eval, below is one such output

Position:
[image]

output of eval
[image]

you can check more example on https://scriptchess.com/free-chess-engine

Comment: What is "static analysis"?

Comment: the output of eval command of stockfish. I thought that's what we call it

Comment: Still not sure what you mean. Are you talking about the function that evaluates the final position of a given line? Maybe "we" call it that way, I don't know much about chess engine development.

Comment: please check the updated question

Comment: Oh, so pretty much that (evaluation without calculation). I'd say totally useless except maybe material count at absolute beginner level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is impossible to answer definitely, except by someone who has made a detailed study of chess engines, and if and how they make static analysis available to end users, and for what purposes that happens.  It does not seem to be a subject of general interest, so you probably will have to do your own research in order to cover 'any chess engine', as stated in your question.

Any static analysis presented by a chess engine is likely to be specific to
that engine or that family of engines. It is unlikely to be intended for
a typical end user; it probably has some use for debug
or troubleshooting purposes. The info from from stockfish is remarkably
extensive -- it may be that it has other uses.

The best answer is to suggest that you ask each engine manufacturer separately. In some
cases, the information may already be present in engine documentation;
in other cases you may have to ask the developer directly.  But you
are most likely to get different replies from each of them.

If you would ask about a specific chess engine, it may be that someone
here already knows.

That from Stockfish may possibly be useful to trace how the individual
attributes change during the course of a game, but I can't see any
immediate practical use for that. (Added: Except perhaps regression testing during development.) Perhaps the Stockfish people can.

Comment: Make sense, Thanks